# Why WebDriver output this html exception

Tags: webdriver

**CODE:**

```
package com.funcybernation.yndextesting;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

**Output** =====

```
HtmlTextInput[<input autocomplete="off" class="lst tiah" value="" title="Пошук Google" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57" style="color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top;padding-right:38px" type="text">] -> HtmlHtml[<html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">]
HtmlTextInput[<input autocomplete="off" class="lst tiah" value="" title="Пошук Google" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57" style="color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top;padding-right:38px" type="text">] -> HtmlHtml[<html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">]
HtmlTextInput[<input autocomplete="off" class="lst tiah" value="" title="Пошук Google" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57" style="color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top;padding-right:38px" type="text">] -> HtmlHtml[<html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">]
HtmlBody[<body bgcolor="#fff">] -> HtmlHtml[<html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">]
HtmlTextInput[<input autocomplete="off" class="lst tiah" value="" title="Пошук Google" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57" style="color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top;padding-right:38px" type="text">] -> HtmlHtml[<html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">]
HtmlTextInput[<input autocomplete="off" class="lst tiah" value="Cheese!" title="Пошук Google" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57" style="color:#000;margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top;padding-right:38px" type="text">] -> HtmlHtml[<html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">]
    Page title is: Cheese! - Search Google
```

Comment: And where is problem? The last line says, that you got where you wanted. The rest will be just standard info log to you so you know that its doing something ...

Comment: i want see only my output without any logs or html. And this is a problem. How i can switch off this logs?

Answer (score 0):

That log information might be coming from HtmlUnit. If so, you should be able to [configure HtmlUnit to reduce the logging](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/logging.html).